# UITableViewCell loading but not displaying

Tags: swift, uitableview, sdcalertview, sdcalertcontroller

I'm trying to programmatically load a `UITableView` into a custom `AlertController` using a vanilla `UITableViewCell`. The `UITableView` displays and `dataSource` methods all get called, but the `UITableViewCell` does not display.

Here is the code:

```
class TemplateTypeSelection : NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var completion : (type:TemplateType)-> Void = { (type) -> Void in }
    var alert : AlertController!

    let myIdentifier = "MyReuseIdentifier";

    func showDialog(completion:(type:TemplateType)-> Void) {

        self.completion = completion
        let alert = AlertController(title: "Select Template", message: nil)

        let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 300), style: .Plain)
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: myIdentifier)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        alert.contentView.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(alert.contentView.topAnchor).active = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(alert.contentView.bottomAnchor).active = true

        tableView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(alert.contentView.leftAnchor).active = true

        alert.present()

    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.completion(type: TemplateType.CastAndCrew)
        alert.dismiss()
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(myIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        var name : String?
        switch(indexPath.row) {
             case 0 : name = TemplateType.CAPS.rawValue
             case 1 : name = TemplateType.CastAndCrew.rawValue
             case 2 : name = TemplateType.EASE.rawValue
             case 3 : name = TemplateType.EP.rawValue
             case 4 : name = TemplateType.Pixpay.rawValue
             default : name = "Empty"
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = name;
        return cell;
    }

}
```

I checked the `hidden` property of the cell and I checked to make sure `tableView` is the same object in the instantiation and the `dataSource` methods.

The only other clue I have is this console message after all of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods are called:

```
2016-04-03 16:49:27.150 TimecardBuddy[18816:1378060] no index path for table cell being reused
2016-04-03 16:49:27.151 TimecardBuddy[18816:1378060] no index path for table cell being reused
2016-04-03 16:49:27.151 TimecardBuddy[18816:1378060] no index path for table cell being reused
2016-04-03 16:49:27.151 TimecardBuddy[18816:1378060] no index path for table cell being reused
2016-04-03 16:49:27.151 TimecardBuddy[18816:1378060] no index path for table cell being reused
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using the view debugger.

Comment: View debugger says there aren't any cells in the tableView. Turns out cellForRowAtIndexPath is churning out empty cells. But why is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier giving me an empty cell?

Comment: When you say "empty", what does that mean?

Comment: The cell itself is not nil, but the labels are 0x0 (doesn't get caught in the ! unwrapper)

Comment: Do you see anything if you set a hardcoded string to the label? Also, are you sure your table view has a width? As it currently stands you're not adding a right-side constraint.

Comment: I have tried hardcoding a string to the label. I do see the tableView with separator lines and scrolling action. Just no textLabels